# Merging expression data

Tags: regex, perl

I have to look up the FBgn ID from one file (.tsv) and look it up in a new file (.txt) with the FBgn ID replaced by the corresponding gene symbol. 
This is for a school assignment, so I'm not looking for answers but more just a push/shove in the right direction.

Here is what I have so far. (I'm very new to programming.)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

#Part 1
my $infile = '/scratch/Drosophila/fb_synonym_fb_2014_05.tsv';

open ( FILE, "<", $infile)
        or die "Cannot open file $!";




my @data = <FILE>;

foreach my$line (@data) {
        my @column = split( /\s+/, $line );
        my $columnID = $column[0];
        next if ( ! defined( $columnID ));

        if ($columnID =~ /(^FBgn\d+)/ ) {
                my $ID = $1;
                print $ID, "\n";
        }
}



#Part2
my %RnaSeq;
my $FBgn;
my $FBgnRnaSeq;


my %RnaSeq = '/scratch/Drosophila/FlyRNAi_data_baseline_vs_EGF.txt';
open (TEXT, "<", %RnaSeq)
        or die "Cannot open file $!";
while (my %RnaSeq = <TEXT>) {
$FBgn = get getSymbols($FBgnRnaSeq);
print "$FBgnRnaSeq";
}
close TEXT;

sub getSymbols {
        my ($GB_file) = @_;
        my $Sym;
        if ($GB_file =~/(/^FBgn.\d+/)\t(\d+)\t(\d+)/{
        print $1, print $2, print $3, "\n";
}

}
else {
        return "error";
}
}
```

Comment: Before we can point you in the right direction, we need to know what direction you're going.  What problems are you having, what are you trying to solve?

Comment: @Miller: Sorry to roll back, but your perltidy "fixed" a couple problems and added some new ones! The last regex pattern isn't legal (and there's a missing parenthesis) and it threw the parser out.

Answer (score 4):

You don't say what problems you're having, but your code isn't valid Perl and won't compile.

Here are some pointers

- You should write just a *very few* lines at a time before checking that your program compiles and does as much as it should so far. Writing an entire program before you test makes it much more difficult to debug
- You should *indent* your code carefully. It's the best way of making your program readable and ensuring that you have balanced pairs of braces and parentheses
- Perl identifiers should use lower-case letters, digits, and underscores. Capital letters are reserved for global identifiers
- A .tsv file is presumably a tab-separated file, so you should split each line on tabs, not the multiple whitespace that you have written
- You should use *"lexical"* file handles. Things like `TEXT` and `FILE` do work but they are very old-fashioned
- Lines read from a file will have a newline character at the end. You almost certainly don't want this, so you should `chomp` the line after it is read
- If you are processing a file line-by-line then you should *read* it one line at a time, instead of reading it *all* into an array and processing the array
- Perl has an `unless`, so `next if (!defined($columnID))` can be written more neatly as `next  unless defined $columnID`. However, there is no way that `$columnID` can be undefined at this point so the statement should be removed
- You are using `%RnaSeq` as the name of the file to be opened. That is a hash, which is a relationship between a set of strings and their corresponding values. You mean `$RnaSeq`
- You are also reading the lines from the file into `%RnaSeq`. This is the same variable as the file name and, while you *could* do that, you would be overwriting the file name string. The name for an input line variable is usually `$line`, but it looks like you may have meant `$FBgnRnaSeq` in this case
- You have mismatched braces `{}` in your subroutine `getSymbols`
- Your subroutine *prints* some information if the pattern match succeeds, and returns `'error'` if it fails. Nothing explicit is returned in the case of a success, and I can't guess what it is that you mean to return

This is how your program should look with those items fixed, but there are a few places where it's not clear what you meant, and I have had to guess or simply leave things as they are. This code compiles, but I am certain that it doesn't do what you need.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $infile = '/scratch/Drosophila/fb_synonym_fb_2014_05.tsv';

open my $tsv_fh, '<', $infile or die "Cannot open file: $!";

while (my $line = <$tsv_fh>) {
    chomp $line;
    my @columns = split /\t/, $line;
    my $column_id = $columns[0];

    if ($column_id =~ /(^FBgn\d+)/) {
        my $id = $1;
        print $id, "\n";
    }
}


my $fbgn;
my $fbgn_rna_seq;

my $rna_seq = '/scratch/Drosophila/FlyRNAi_data_baseline_vs_EGF.txt';

open my $text_fh, '<', $rna_seq or die "Cannot open file: $!";

while (my $fbgn_rna_seq = <$text_fh>) {
    chomp $fbgn_rna_seq;
    my $fbgn = get_symbols($fbgn_rna_seq);
    print $fbgn_rna_seq, "\n";
}
close $text_fh;

sub get_symbols {
    my ($gb_file) = @_;
    my $sym;
    if ($gb_file =~ /(^FBgn.\d+)\t(\d+)\t(\d+)/ ) {
        print $1, print $2, print $3, "\n";
    }
    else {
        return "error";
    }
}
```